# create-react-app is not working since version 4.0.1 how to remove the old version and install the new version of it

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I enter `npx create-react-app ./` command for creating a react app it gives the following warning and not creating the app

```
Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

When I enter `- npm uninstall -g create-react-app` command, and then I entered gain  `npx create-react-app ./` again gives the above error

**Updated**

I uninstalled with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` 
and again installed with `npm install -g create-react-app` 
and then created my app with `npx create-react-app ./`
I already created a folder inside that folder I created my project so no need to gave project name I used `./` it will create your project inside that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

Uninstall with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Install with `npm install -g create-react-app` and try again

You could also try using `npm init`: `npm init react-app myapp`

Comment: Thanks sir for answering

Comment: Glad I  could help! thank you for accepting

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` 
and again installed with `npm install -g create-react-app` 
and then created my app with `npx create-react-app ./`
I already created a folder inside that folder I created my project so no need to gave project name I used `./` it will create your project inside that folder

Comment: Hello @Abdol, could you re-accept my answer? It is the solution, you don't get extra reputation for accepting your own answer... I already gave +1 on your question

Comment: I already gave +1 on your question but I will give you +1 on answer for extra explanation

Comment: Thanks you so much sir